# Getting expired domain name - most effective route?

Tags: domains, expires

There is a domain name I have been wanting for years that was used as a parked page (read: cybersquatted) that has entered into WHOIS's `redemptionPeriod` stage.

The domain has been `expired` for 61 days now - after contacting the Registar, they informed me that it would stay in redemption for **75 days**. After which, it would either be sold to resellers, or sent back to the public registry. (*I have since sent a followup message requesting the reseller they use.*)

**My question is:** What is the best way to proceed?

I know there is at least one competitor that would love to have this name, but I'm unsure if they even know it's expiring. I did not tell the Registar the domain in question, as they seem geared *towards* cybersquatting, and I do not trust them. Domain Front Running sucks.

Should I use a backorder service? Should I just take my chances and try to grab it after75 days?

I checked an auctionhouse by manually browsing their expired domains - it wasn't there.

Comment: The information you are requesting can be specific to current domain registrar that is holding the domain. Also, it should do you no harm to disclose it, so that might help getting a more specific answer.

Comment: You do not have to expose your desired domain name to me. I would use a quality registrar and see if you can back-order it. The larger the registrar the better. The reason for this is because they may actually work to get it to you. Do not use a cheap company for the same reason. I do not recommend Network Solutions, but maybe GoDaddy since they have been square and honest with me for many years and have never failed me.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to back-order the domain name with a reputable and established Domain Name provider such as 123-reg, GoDaddy, eNom. Obviously there will be a battle as to which provider is quickest at registering once the clock runs out so hopefully you're the only person with it on back-order!